# How to use Espresso testing Recycler view in a fragment getting data with volley using IdlingResource

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

will, I have a MainActivity That Holds MainFragment,
MainFragment implements a RecipeDataFetcher callback interface that brings data got through Volley/network in RecipeDataFetcher Class.
MainFragment has a recyclerview that is suppose to display a couple of recipes cards

-I need to execute a test on a RecyclerView item

Here's my main fragment`public class

```
MainFragment extends Fragment implements RecipesRecyclerAdapter.OnRecipeItemSelected,
        RecipesDataFetcher.RecipesFetcherDataListener {

    private View v;
    private RecipesDataFetcher recipesDataFetcher;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecipesRecyclerAdapter recipesRecyclerAdapter;
private Recipes mRecipes;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;


private SimpleIdlingResource mIdlingResource;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    mRecipes = new Recipes();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv_recipes);
    if (mTwoPanel) {
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    } else {
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    }

    recipesRecyclerAdapter = new RecipesRecyclerAdapter(this, mRecipes);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recipesRecyclerAdapter);
    return v;
}

@VisibleForTesting
@NonNull
public SimpleIdlingResource getIdlingResource() {
    if (mIdlingResource == null) {
        mIdlingResource = new SimpleIdlingResource();
    }
    return mIdlingResource;
}



   @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
//        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(int itemPosition) {
    mListener.onFragmentInteraction(mRecipes.get(itemPosition), mRecipes.size());
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mRecipes.isEmpty()) {
        getData();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailure() {
    if (!checkOnlineState(getActivity())) {
        Logging.shortToast(getActivity(), getString(R.string.internet_error));
    } else {
        Logging.shortToast(getActivity(), getString(R.string.server_error));
    }
}

private void getData() {
    recipesDataFetcher = new RecipesDataFetcher(getActivity(), this);
    recipesDataFetcher.getRecipes(mIdlingResource);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionDone(Recipes recipes) {

    mRecipes.addAll(recipes);
    recipesRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //TODO: Do bulk inset in a background thread and for once
    ContentValues[] contentValues = new ContentValues[recipes.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < recipes.size(); i++) {
        ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String ingredients = gson.toJson(recipes.get(i).getIngredients());
        String steps = gson.toJson(recipes.get(i).getSteps());
        contentValue.put(COLUMN_RECIPE_INGREDIENTS, ingredients);
        contentValue.put(COLUMN_RECIPE_STEPS, steps);
        contentValue.put(COLUMN_RECIPE_SERVINGS, recipes.get(i).getServings());
        contentValue.put(COLUMN_RECIPE_IMAGE, recipes.get(i).getImage());
        contentValue.put(COLUMN_RECIPE_NAME, recipes.get(i).getName());
        contentValues[i] = contentValue;
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().bulkInsert(CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

    if(mIdlingResource!=null){
        mIdlingResource.setIdleState(true);
    }

}


public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Recipe recipe, int size);
}`
```

and here is my dataFetching class

```
public class RecipesDataFetcher extends BaseDataFetcher {
    public RecipesDataFetcher(Context context, BaseDataFetcherListener mListener) {
        super(context, mListener);
    }



    public void getRecipes(SimpleIdlingResource simpleIdlingResource) {
            if(simpleIdlingResource!=null){
            simpleIdlingResource.setIdleState(false);}
        String URL = BaseURL;
    Logging.log("getCountries: " + URL);
    JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, (JSONArray jsonArr) -> {
        Logging.log("getCountries response: " + jsonArr.toString());
        Recipes recipes = new Recipes(jsonArr);
        ((RecipesFetcherDataListener) mListener).onConnectionDone(recipes);
        if(simpleIdlingResource!=null){
            simpleIdlingResource.setIdleState(true);
        }
    }, this.errorListener);
    retryPolicy(jsonObjReq);
    getReQ().add(jsonObjReq);
}

public interface RecipesFetcherDataListener extends BaseDataFetcherListener {
    void onConnectionDone(Recipes recipes);
}
```

}

An Here is My testing class

```
 @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
    public class MyFragmentTest {   

        private SimpleIdlingResource mIdlingResource;

    @Rule
    public FragmentTestRule<MainFragment> mFragmentTestRule = new FragmentTestRule<>(MainFragment.class);

    @Before
    public void registerIdlingResource() {
        // Launch the activity to make the fragment visible
        mFragmentTestRule.launchActivity(null);
         mIdlingResource = mFragmentTestRule.getFragment().getIdlingResource();
        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
    }

    @Test
    public void fragment_can_be_instantiated() {


        // Then to test item in position 0
        onView(withId(R.id.rv_recipes))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
    }

    //  unregister resources
    @After
    public void unregisterIdlingResource() {
        if (mIdlingResource != null) {
            Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
        }
    }
}
```

And Finally [here](https://github.com/aya-salama1989/BackingApp) is the whole code project, just let me know what am i doing wrong exactly :D, Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you remind the issue you faced !?

Comment: @IbrahimAli what do you mean by reminding the issue? :/

Answer (score 1):

***Explanation for the errors***

After having a tour at your repository and run the   **MyFragmentTest** Test Class

i faced two errors which are

1. java.lang.RuntimeException: com.baking.www.baking.utilities.TestActivity@1d6e5b2 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

This happens because in the **FragmentTestRule** Class you extends ActivityTestRule <**TestActivity**>  where **TestActivity** not implement OnFragmentInteractionListener so the solution to this is you have to extends **MainActivity** which already implement this interface so this class should be look like this :

```
public class FragmentTestRule<F extends Fragment> extends ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> {

private final Class<F> mFragmentClass;
private F mFragment;

public FragmentTestRule(final Class<F> fragmentClass) {
    super(MainActivity.class, true, false);
    mFragmentClass = fragmentClass;
}
.....
```

2. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.baking.www.baking.IdlingResource.SimpleIdlingResource com.baking.www.baking.fragments.MainFragment.getIdlingResource()' on a null object reference

This happens because in your **MyFragmentTest** 
the annotation **@Before** is called before anything started which leads to that your fragment was not yet created that make this line not make sense

```
 mIdlingResource = mFragmentTestRule.getFragment().getIdlingResource();
```

So in my point of view :
Do not use Fragments. Activities are easier to test. You can test each Activity on its own. In most cases Fragments offer no advantage over Activities. Fragments just make the implementation and testing more difficult.

***Alternative Solution to run the idling resources with volley***

(a) in **MainActivity.java**

add these lines

```
@Nullable
public SimpleIdlingResource mIdlingResource;

@VisibleForTesting
@NonNull
public SimpleIdlingResource getIdlingResource() {
    if (mIdlingResource == null) {
        mIdlingResource = new SimpleIdlingResource();
    }
    return mIdlingResource;
}
```

and in your **onCreate** call this method 
        getIdlingResource();
to take instance from idlingResouce.

(b) in MainFragment.java

- remove the class variable **mIdlingResource** and it's getMethod
- you will find errors for **mIdlingResource**
- replace any **mIdlingResource** with ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mIdlingResource

(c) and finally this is the new **MainActivityTest**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

private IdlingResource mIdlingResource;


// Registers any resource that needs to be synchronized with Espresso before the test is run.
@Before
public void registerIdlingResource() {
    mIdlingResource = mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getIdlingResource();
    // To prove that the test fails, omit this call:
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
}

@Test
public void idlingResourceTest() {
    onView(withId(R.id.rv_recipes)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.rv_recipes))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
}

// Remember to unregister resources when not needed to avoid malfunction.
@After
public void unregisterIdlingResource() {
    if (mIdlingResource != null) {
        Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
    }
}

}
```

Sorry for the long answer hope i helped :) :)